# Retrieve large objects with multiprocessing.Pipe

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, out-of-memory, psutil

I'm current working in a RAM monitoring decorator:

```
import time
import asyncio
import multiprocessing as mp

import psutil
import numpy as np


class MemoryMonitor:

    def __init__(
        self,
        threshold=115343360, # Bytes
        delay=1              # Seconds
    ):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.delay = delay

    async def __memory_info(self, pid):
        memory = psutil.Process(pid).memory_info().rss
        print(f'Monitoring RAM: current value={memory}')
        if memory > self.threshold:
            print(f'Memory threashold exceeded: thr={self.threshold}, current={memory}')
            return True
        return False
    
    async def __ram_monitoring(self, process):
        while process.is_alive():
            memory_error = await asyncio.gather(self.__memory_info(process.pid))
            if memory_error[0]:
                if process.is_alive():
                    process.kill()
                raise MemoryError(f'Memory exceeded threshold={self.threshold}')
            await asyncio.sleep(self.delay)

    def __call__(self, **monitoring_kwargs):
        def monitoring_decorator(func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                # Target function to collect retrived valued of decorated function
                def target(*args, **kwargs):
                    try:
                        cconn.send([func(*args, **kwargs), False])
                    except Exception as exc:
                        cconn.send([exc, True])

                pconn, cconn = mp.Pipe(duplex=False)

                # Call the function in a different process 
                # to be able to kill the process if memory is exceeded
                process = mp.Process(target=target, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
                process.start()

                # Run the ram monitorin process in async mode
                asyncio.run(self.__ram_monitoring(process=process))

                # Collect the decorated function retrived valued
                value, error = pconn.recv()
                if error:
                    raise value
                return value
            return wrapper
        return monitoring_decorator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    memory_monitor = MemoryMonitor(threshold=2.5e+7)

    @memory_monitor()
    def test_function(n):
        for i in range(n):
            v = np.ones([i,i])
            time.sleep(0.1)
        return v

    v = test_function(100)
    print(v)
```

I'm using:

0. Linux operating system
1. Asynchronous functions to collect the RAM memory value with `psutil` library.
2. `multiprocessing.Process` to run the decorated function
3. And `multiprocessing.Pipe` to collect the retrieved value of the decorated function

The process works fine, it kills the process if the RAM memory is exceeded:

```
Memory threashold exceeded: thr=25000000.0, current=25014272
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 98, in <module>
    v = test_function(500)
  File "main.py", line 77, in wrapper
    asyncio.run(self.__ram_monitoring(process=process))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 56, in __ram_monitoring
    raise MemoryError(f'Memory exceeded threshold={self.threshold}')
MemoryError: Memory exceeded threshold=25000000.0
```

And returns the value of the decorated function:

```
Monitoring RAM: current value=22700032
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
Main.py DONE
```

The problem is when I'm trying to recover a large value (like a `numpy.ones([100,100])`); the process gets stuck in `cconn.send(func(*args, **kwargs))` and never ends.

Question:

How can I recover large values with `multiprocessing.Pipe` or `multiprocessing.Queue`?  [I read this post:](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-numpy-efficiently-between-processes-1bee17dcb01), he suggests `multiprocessing.Array` and `multiprocessing.Value`, however, I cannot always predict the type and shape of the returned value.

Or am I using a wrong approach (asynchronous functions + multiprocessing)?

Comment: Reading your code, one obvious error is that you are not reading and writing to the pipe at the same time. If the data you put into the pipe is big enough that it might become full, one thread/process then must read data from the other side to prevent deadlocks. So you should edit your code such that the function `__ram_monitoring` accepts the `pconn` connection object. Then, your while loop condition should become `while process.is_alive() and not pconn.poll()` inside `ram_monitoring`. That should clear up this issue.

Comment: also from [`multiprocessing.connection.Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection): "Very large pickles/buffers (approximately 32 MiB+, though it depends on the OS) may raise a ValueError exception"